# Signal Handling in thread c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, signals

i have read it everywhere that mutex cannot be used in signal handler as that can make the program to hang. If other thread has already locked the mutex and before the release of the mutex signal handler is called then it would put the application in dead lock.

But, what happens when a signal is send to the specific thread from let's say a kernel module through sendsiginfo ?. In the signal handler function i had put a sleep of 20 seconds at that time if i see my other threads are working and doing there respective tasks.

So, does signal handling behaves differently when a signal is directly sent to the thread? Does it mean that as it will not run on the main application context and run on the thread context which is handling the signal we can use pthread calls ? like mutex and stuff ?